# symbol lookup error: /snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: undefined symbol: __libc_pthread_init, version GLIBC_PRIVATE

Tags: ros-humble

I was  trying to setup a simple transform broadcaster by following [Write a broadcaster (Python)](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Intermediate/Tf2/Writing-A-Tf2-Broadcaster-Py.html) from [ROS2 Humble documentation](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/index.html).

I created the `package`, `nodes`, `launch` files, and everything else, including the addition of `entry points`, `data files` etc., and the package was successfully built using `colcon`. But when I tried to **launch** the node using the below command, an error occurred. I don't know what went wrong; but, in order to rectify any human error in following the steps, I tried doing the same thing multiple times and resulted in the same error.

**Launch command** I executed (given in the docs)

```bash
ros2 launch learning_tf2_py turtle_tf2_demo.launch.py
```

**ERROR Log**

```bash
jishnu@Legion:~/robotics/ros-git/tf2$ ros2 launch learning_tf2_py turtle_tf2_demo.launch.py
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/jishnu/.ros/log/2023-04-07-19-06-58-821889-Legion-2160358
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [turtlesim_node-1]: process started with pid [2160368]
[INFO] [turtle_tf2_broadcaster-2]: process started with pid [2160370]
[turtlesim_node-1] QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread
[turtlesim_node-1] /opt/ros/humble/lib/turtlesim/turtlesim_node: symbol lookup error: /snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: undefined symbol: __libc_pthread_init, version GLIBC_PRIVATE
[ERROR] [turtlesim_node-1]: process has died [pid 2160368, exit code 127, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/turtlesim/turtlesim_node --ros-args -r __node:=sim'].
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Java: symbol lookup error: /snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: undefined symbol: __libc_pthread_init, version GLIBC_PRIVATE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75921414/4424636) on Stack Overflow:

> Though I have already answered it [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1462295/ubuntu-22-04-both-eye-of-gnome-and-gimp-failing-with-undefined-symbol-error/1462494#1462494)
>
> The issue with how the VSCode Snap package libraries are configured to be used. They are setting the following environment variable GTK_PATH, which gets inherited by the VSCode Terminal.
>
> Unsetting the environment variable in the VSCode terminal does seem to work for me.
>
> ```
> unset GTK_PATH
> ```
>
> Or you can clear out the environment variable by using the VSCode Configuration, as mentioned in the other answer.

You will probably need to run `unset GTK_PATH` each new session/login/reboot. To set it permanently, put the command in your profile.

**Note**: It is a good idea to make a note of what the value of `GTK_PATH` is, prior to unsetting it - that way you can revert it back to its previous value, should you encounter any issues. To see what its "usual" value is, run `echo $GTK_PATH`, prior to unsetting it... If you have already unset it, open a new terminal window, which *should* have the unset value of `GTK_PATH` (if not, try a reboot).

Comment: Thanks it worked for me! But are there any side effects or other issues caused on unsetting the `GTK_PATH` environment variable, and is it a single time process or should I need to do it each and every time?